# Will there be Community Promotion Ads in 2020, if so when?

Tags: support, community-promotion-ads

Will Community Promotion Ads be returning this year? In previous years, a post was put up on meta (Chem, Math, Phys) sometime between December and early February. Is it just delayed or is this feature no longer going to be supported?

Comment: They have been posted on several meta sites now: https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1381/ https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2599/

Comment: Related:  Free Vote-Based Advertisement for an Open Source Project: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394409/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update:** Just posted these on 100 sites :)

---

**Community Promotion Ads are still coming in 2020!**

I'm sorry for the delay: there's been a lot of things to juggle lately, and that's the only reason why they haven't been posted yet. It's a manual process, so it requires a bit of time to take care of it, but I have it on my schedule to try to post these this week (or by the end of the next one, at the latest) on all non-beta sites.

Comment: Congrats with [the badges](https://stackexchange.com/users/1399708/jnat?tab=activity) ;)

Comment: you have to post 100 posts manually? :-o

Comment: I did, yes, @Ooker

Comment: Why don't you (SE) automate it? Is there any advantage of manually doing so?

Comment: There's no advantage, @Ooker. Its automation has just been deprioritized, in general.

Comment: may I ask why is that?