# Are community ads still a thing?

Tags: discussion, advertising, community-promotion-ads

Are community ads still a thing? [The last activity on the offical tag was in 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads?tab=Newest), and I can’t remember when I last saw a community ad banner (this might be due to ad blocking, although I’ve in principle disabled it on Stack Exchange sites).

I’m asking since the [Bioinformatics.SE community](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) is interested in [advertising its community](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/144/29).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we get Community Promotion Ads on beta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248214/how-do-we-get-community-promotion-ads-on-beta-sites), see also [Will there be Community Promotion Ads in 2020, if so when?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344512/398063)

Comment: @Jenayah Yes it does, thanks!

Comment: Regarding "last activity on official tag was in 2013": that's not really true. Community promotion ads posts are hosted on per-site metas, not here on Meta Stack Exchange, as they are specific to each site. The reason you see those earlier posts here is because of the site's history: prior to April 2014, this site (Meta.SE) was called "Meta Stack Overflow" and served as both the network meta site *and* the per-site meta for Stack Overflow. Around that time, this site was renamed and rescoped, with a new per-site meta established for SO. Only the active 2014 post was migrated to that new site.